How to configure Entra ID app registration to return the user's email in access tokens?
How can I configure Entra ID app registrations to return the user's email in access tokens?
In "Token configuration", I specify that the email should be included in access tokens. However, for users with emails, the emails are not included in access tokens?


What do you mean by email? An Office365 mailbox or on premises Exchange mailbox?
